# Pegar código de uma li

Tags: javascript, jquery

Preciso pegar a `<li>` completa de todo `checkbox` marcado.

Meu código que é montado dinamicamente está abaixo:

```
HTMLNovo = '
    <li class="item item-checkbox widget uib_w_69" data-uib="ionic/checkbox" data-ver="0">
        <label class="checkbox">
            <input class="check ckeckVisitantes" type="checkbox" name="'+pessoa.COD_IDENT_PESSO+'">
            <input id="codigoPessoaPresente" value="'+pessoa.COD_IDENT_PESSO+'" type="hidden">
        </label>'+ pessoa.TXT_NOMEX_PESSO +'
    </li>';
```

Preciso pegar todo este li, dos que estiverem marcados na pagina.

Hoje estou conseguindo pegar apenas os IDs.

```
var inputElements = document.getElementsByClassName('ckeckVisitantes');
for(var i = 0; inputElements[i]; ++i){
    if(inputElements[i].checked)
        arr.push(inputElements[i].name);
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você só precisa substituir a seguinte linha de código:

```
arr.push(inputElements[i].name);
```

por esta:

```
arr.push(inputElements[i].parentNode.parentNode);
```

Mas me deixei fazer uma sugestão, no lugar de consultar todos os checkboxes para então verificar quais estão marcados, você pode fazer isto direto no seletor, então o seguinte trecho de codigo

```
var inputElements = document.getElementsByClassName('ckeckVisitantes');
for(var i=0; inputElements[i]; ++i){
  if(inputElements[i].checked)
    arr.push(inputElements[i].parentNode.parentNode);
}
```

pode ser simplificado para o seguinte:

```
var inputElements = document.querySelectorAll('.ckeckVisitantes:checked');
for(var i=0; inputElements[i]; ++i) {
  arr.push(inputElements[i].parentNode.parentNode);
}
```

por fim, no lugar de montar as suas linhas usando strings, você pode usar um recurso do HTML5... Templates:

No HTML você teria algo como:

```
<template id="tmplLinha">
  <li class="item item-checkbox widget uib_w_69" data-uib="ionic/checkbox" data-ver="0">
    <label class="checkbox labelVisitantes">
      <input type="checkbox" class="check ckeckVisitantes" />
      <input type="hidden" class="hiddenVisitantes" />
    </label>
  </li>
</template>
```

E no javaScript teria algo como:

```
pessoas.forEach(function (pessoa, indice) {
  var linha = document.importNode(tmplLinha, true);
  var label = linha.querySelector(".labelVisitantes");
  var check = linha.querySelector(".ckeckVisitantes");
  var hidden = linha.querySelector(".hiddenVisitantes");  
  var texto = document.createTextNode(pessoa.TXT_NOMEX_PESSO);

  label.appendChild(texto);  
  check.name = pessoa.COD_IDENT_PESSO;
  hidden.value = pessoa.COD_IDENT_PESSO;  
  container.appendChild(linha);
});
```

pode parecer complicado e o código ficar maior, mas neste caso você deixa de manipular strings e passa a manipular elementos, e isto melhora e muito o desempenho do código.

Segue o exemplo completo:

```js
var tmplLinha = document.getElementById("tmplLinha").content;
var container = document.getElementById("container");
var getSelecionados = document.getElementById("getSelecionados");

var pessoas = [];
for (var indice = 1; indice <= 10; indice++) {
  var pessoa = {};
  pessoa.COD_IDENT_PESSO = indice;
  pessoa.TXT_NOMEX_PESSO = "Pessoa " + indice;
  pessoas.push(pessoa);
}

pessoas.forEach(function (pessoa, indice) {
  var linha = document.importNode(tmplLinha, true);
  var label = linha.querySelector(".labelVisitantes");
  var check = linha.querySelector(".ckeckVisitantes");
  var hidden = linha.querySelector(".hiddenVisitantes");  
  var texto = document.createTextNode(pessoa.TXT_NOMEX_PESSO);
  
  label.appendChild(texto);  
  check.name = pessoa.COD_IDENT_PESSO;
  hidden.value = pessoa.COD_IDENT_PESSO;  
  container.appendChild(linha);
});


var onGetSelecionadosClick = function (event) {
  //listando checkbox selecionados;
  var selecionados = container.querySelectorAll(".ckeckVisitantes:checked");
  
  //listando linhas à que os checkboxes selecionados pertecem.
  var linhas = [].map.call(selecionados, function (selecionado, indice) {
    return selecionado.parentNode.parentNode;
  });
  
  //remotando o modelo (Pessoa) para os checkbox selecionados.
  var pessoas = [].map.call(linhas, function (linha, indice) {
    var label = linha.querySelector(".labelVisitantes");
    var hidden = linha.querySelector(".hiddenVisitantes");
    return {
      TXT_NOMEX_PESSO: label.textContent.trim(),
      COD_IDENT_PESSO: hidden.value
    };
  });
  console.log(selecionados, linhas, pessoas);
}

getSelecionados.addEventListener("click", onGetSelecionadosClick);
```

```html
<template id="tmplLinha">
  <li class="item item-checkbox widget uib_w_69" data-uib="ionic/checkbox" data-ver="0">
    <label class="checkbox labelVisitantes">
      <input type="checkbox" class="check ckeckVisitantes" />
      <input type="hidden" class="hiddenVisitantes" />
    </label>
  </li>
</template>

<ul id="container">
</ul>

<button id="getSelecionados" >Obter Pessoas Selecionadas</button>
```

Comment: Ai sim heim! +1

Comment: Muito bom, não utilizei o seu metodo, pois estava pensando e isto não iria sanar meus problemas, porque ele viria ja preenchido, preciso que ele viria de outra forma, porem a solução do meu problema foi pegar o id e ir no banco de dados verificar quem é aquele id, e montar o li novamente na outra pagina, e funcionou. Muito obrigado, fica marcado com certa sua resposta,

Answer (score 3):

> Explicando a troca do [parents](https://api.jquery.com/parents/) pelo
>   [parent](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) conforme citado pelo
>   @TobyMosque 
>   **Parents**: Irá trazer uma lista com todos os elementos anteriores. 
>   **Parent**: Irá trazer apenas um elemento pai, no nosso caso estamos usando o seletor *li* que é opcional.

```
$('.ckeckVisitantes').parent('li');
```

Para selecionar o li pai do checkbox checked, utilize o atributo `checked`

```
$("input:checkbox[class*=ckeckVisitantes]:checked").parent('li');
```

Comment: assim irei pegar o li todo ?

Comment: Mais preciso pegar os parents so marcados.

Comment: Acredito que seja preciso adicionar um evento para quando uma checkbox for marcada, selecionar o parent dela, e ainda, detalhe **importante** no código do autor, feche o label com a tag </label> senão o parent não irá funcionar!

Comment: A label está fechada. Porem o que você falou não funcionou, na verdade eu coloquei um (this). para ele pegar o que está chegado, porem ele não está retornando o código e sim o apontador para o código, preciso do código.

Comment: @RenanRodrigues alterei a resposta.

Comment: Não está voltando o que quero

Comment: Coloquei uma foto para você ver.

Comment: Está retornando o elemento "li" conforme você pediu. Se você atribuir ele a uma variável poderá acessar todas as propriedades dele. :)

Comment: Só uma dica, como quer trazer apenas a primeira `li` (a mais próxima), deve utilizar `.parent("li")` ao invés de `.parents("li")`, pois se tivemos uma lista dentro de outra, o `.parents("li")`vai trazer todas as li até o elemento raiz.

Comment: Ta certo. Parents irá trazer todas mesmo, nesse caso precisaremos apenas da primeira. Valeu @TobyMosque vou alterar a resposta.

Answer (score 3):

Se for para pegar apenas a `li` utilize `.parentNode` para poder navegar nas suas tags.

```js
 var inputElements = document.getElementsByClassName('ckeckVisitantes');
 for (var i = 0; inputElements[i]; ++i) {
   if (inputElements[i].checked) {
     console.log(inputElements[i].parentNode.parentNode);
   }
 }
```

```html
<li class="item item-checkbox widget uib_w_69" data-uib="ionic/checkbox" data-ver="0">
  <label class="checkbox">
    <input class="check ckeckVisitantes" type="checkbox" name="'+pessoa.COD_IDENT_PESSO+'" checked>
    <input id="codigoPessoaPresente" value="'+pessoa.COD_IDENT_PESSO+'" type="hidden">
  </label>Exemplo</li>
```

Saida:

```
 <li class="item item-checkbox widget uib_w_69" data-ver="0" data-uib="ionic/checkbox">
```

Comment: O que você fez, retorna apenas do primeiro os outros dão erro.

Comment: O erro está descrito na foto da postagem.

Comment: Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to read the 'selectionDirection' property from 'HTMLInputElement': The input element's type ('checkbox') does not support selection.